# Where is the actual entrance to Zagreb airport (Zračna luka Franjo Tuđman)?

Tags: walking, airport-terminals, zagreb, zag

I am confused about the exact location of the (departures) entrance to the Zagreb airport.

[Searching for Google Maps direction](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Zagreb,+Croatia/Franjo+Tu%C4%91man+Airport+Zagreb+(ZAG),+Ul.+Rudolfa+Fizira+1,+10150,+Zagreb,+Croatia/@45.7395349,16.0787281,16.75z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x4765d692c902cc39:0x3a45249628fbc28a!2m2!1d15.9819189!2d45.8150108!1m5!1m1!1s0x47667ee85c7fab29:0x9ef60b3c28e288f6!2m2!1d16.0674366!2d45.7407504!3e2) to the airport places the destination point somewhere around (45.741151, 16.081114). This is also the part of the map that is shown on their official site when searching for driving directions to the airport *and* it is also close to the official airport's address, Ulica Rudolfa Fizira 21.

However, the satellite imagery does not show the roads sketched out on the map of this part and the terminal location seems to be somewhere around [(45.732079, 16.060357)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/45%C2%B043'55.5%22N+16%C2%B003'37.3%22E/@45.7315981,16.0598425,372m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d45.7320792!4d16.0603573).

I remember that the entrance is overlooking the park seen at these coordinates. I thought that the terminal perhaps moved, [having found this piece of news about the new terminal](https://www.total-croatia-news.com/business/17655-new-terminal-at-zagreb-airport-officially-opened). To add to my confusion, I realized this must have been already built the last time I was at the airport, but the photos do not ring a bell.

I would like to know the precise location to estimate the feasibility of walking to the airport from a nearby hotel. The two points in question are more than 2 km apart according to Google Maps.

Comment: There seems to be two terminals: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/45.7344/16.0617
The old one is close to some built-up area. The new one is not walkable to anything. There's huge parking but nothing else. What terminal is in your ticket?

Comment: The tickets don't specify the terminal. Also, on the official airport webpage, there is only a map of *one* terminal, and it says the new one. Perhaps the old terminal (or entrance) is not used anymore at all.
Thanks for looking into this, @alamar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After flying from the airport I can attest that the new terminal is in use. It's located at [45.741275, 16.081007](https://www.google.com/maps/place/45%C2%B044'28.6%22N+16%C2%B004'51.6%22E/@45.7412891,16.0722522,3540m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d45.7412745!4d16.0810068).

Nowhere was it specified that I should use the "new" terminal. However, the bus station in front of the old one says *The old passenger terminal* (hr. Stari putnički terminal), implying that it's not in use any more. Additionally, while the bus was passing it, it's doors seemed to be sealed.

As an aside: the satellite imagery of this location is already updated when using the map on an Android phone. From a PC browser, I cannot see the updated imagery.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be [two terminals](http://openstreetmap.org/#map=15/45.7344/16.0617).

The old one is close to some built-up area. The new one is not walkable to anything. There's huge parking but nothing else.

What terminal is in your ticket? I assume that new terminal is used exclusively and you can't walk anywhere from there. Try to catch some shuttle.